# Segmentation Fault while printing char array through pointer in C

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am brushing up some on C coding for embedded programming, and I can't figure out why the following is throwing a segmentation fault error. I thought that by checking whether the pointer is pointing to `NULL` would suffice, but it does not seem the case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

char json[] = "Authentication:YERL90\nredLedBri:400\nredLedOn:true\n";
char inData[100];

void printBuffer(char * buf) {
    cout << "...printing buffer:" << endl;
    char * p = buf;
    while(p) {
        cout << *p << endl;
        p++;
    }
    cout << "...end printing" << endl;

}

void resetBuffer(char * buf)
{
  memset(&buf[0], 0, sizeof(buf));
}


int main()
{

   printBuffer(json);

   return 0;
}
```

Any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: Off topic: I would prefer `for(char const *p = buf; *p; ++p) cout << *p << std::endl;`. This way the scope of p is limited, p is pointer to `const`, which can prevent accident. Stepping is also on a dedicated place. BTW `printBuffer` should accept `char const * buf`, because it does not want to write into the buffer. Also in `resetBuffer` `&buf[0]` is unnecessary, you can write `buf`. The `sizeof(buf)` expression will be evaluated to the size of a pointer not as size of the array behind the pointer. You need to accept size there. Or google "Template parameter deduction from array dimensions"

Comment: @Notinlist Thanks for pointing that out. I will amend my code to reflect your suggestions. Cheers!

Comment: `cout << "...printing buffer:" << endl;` In C, a string literal cannot be the rightside operand of a `<<` operator. Maybe you are using C++?

Comment: @wildplasser I am using `cout` only to debug the code. The code belongs originally to a MCU where I am planning to parse incoming JSON data via C. I find it easier to debug it with a remote compiler instead of uploading the file to the MCU all the time.

Comment: Please use the correct language tags.

Comment: Sure, I will update the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking the address instead of the value at the address.

Replace `while(p)` with `while(*p)`